Concept related to the rank of the group, but with generated set instead of the generated subgroup, does it have a name?
I've edited the question, originally I asked about the rank of a group and some other things, I have refined the question to make it more appropriate.
So as I am now aware, the rank of a group $G$ is the minimum size of a subset $S \subseteq G$ such that $\langle S \rangle = G$. However this rank is defined using the concept of the generated subgroup that a subset of a group induces. I am interested in the generated subset, which might or might not be a group, that a subset induces in the following way: $W_S = \{s_1s_2...s_n | n \in \mathbb{N} \land s_i \in S\}$. So in other words, I want to know if there is a name for the minimum size of $S \subseteq G$ such that $W_S = G$.
An example of this is the symmetric group $S_3$, it technically has six elements, however you can find two that generate all the other ones. You can view one element as a rotation of the triangle, another as a reflection, and all others will be a combination of these two. So does this number have a name?

Please search before asking, e.g. the obvious search group-theoretic analog of dimension of a vector space immediately yields what you seek.

@BillDubuque Sorry, but I did ask my professor before asking here and he told me he didn't know, and he said it in a way that made me think such a concept didn't even exist, so I didn't even bother looking for it. Besides I did ask other related questions.

We do expect you to do research before asking questions. If your algebra prof. doesn't know about basic concepts like the rank of a group then they are not well-versed. Also, you are supposed to ask only one question per post.

@BillDubuque I'll do more research next time, I can delete the question if that's what is appropriate.

@BillDubuque I have edited the question, now it should be more clear and I also deleted the part asking for a "googleable" question.

As for the first question, that's the rank of a group.
As for the rest, you should not ignore the fact that the inverses belong to the data of a group. But you are essentially forgetting that here and are only considering the underlying monoid. Here one also has the notion of a rank (you will find more under the search term "rank of a semigroup").

Thanks for enlightening me about the rank. You have given me new concepts to research about, but I am not quite sure of what you mean by "data of a group". Could you go into more details?

The correct definition of a group (which unfortunately is not used so often) is that it consists of a set, a binary operation (multiplication), a constant (the neutral element) and an unary operation (inverse) satisfying some axioms. So it makes absolutely sense that, when looking at generated subgroups, we also apply inverses etc. And it doesn't make much sense to just apply products. This is not quite true for the incorrect (but more common) definition that groups are semigroups with the property that neutral and inverse elements exist. For example, the generated abelian subgroup is...

...is expected to being the same as the generated subgroup, given a subset of an abelian group. This is because we have the same operations. But the generated sub-semigroup is not the same as the generated subgroup. So this is why I don't think we should teach groups that way. And I think this also set the background for your second question, I think.
